# Javascript: Find string with number in a document

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a document which has a string of the following form:

"vestuvems.lt is ranked number 5,254,602 in the world according to the Alexa Traffic Rank"

where the name vestuvems.lt and the value for 5,254,602 will change. How can I write a regex expression to obtain only the above string from the document and then extract the number from that string.

I have tried the following which does not work:

```
new RegExp(" is ranked number \d+ in the world according to the Alexa Traffic Rank");
```

Comment: Double backslashes. `\\d`. Or best use a literal regex notation `/.../`.

Comment: It doesn't work when I use \\d or /.../ because the number has commas. I don't understand why it is a duplicate

Comment: Working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/liototo/badhe9sc/1/

Comment: So, use `\d+(:,\d+)*` (or there other more reliable patterns, it depends on the input).

Comment: @RiyafaAbdulHameed because it's a basic number matching

Comment: @stribizhev it could use a comma instead of a dot. AH!